# Changing Java code after deployment

Tags: java, deployment, compilation

When distributing a Java application to others, it can be deployed as a JAR file for easy execution.
But is there a way to change a Java class / part of the code after deployment without having to rebundle the whole application again? 
If you have an app with say 10 classes where 9 are finalized but one needs to be adjusted according to the individual case. What would be the easiest way to change just one class in an app?

Comment: No, there's no.  You should repackage.

Comment: like an eclipse update site?

Comment: This does sound a whole lot like "I am in need of reloadable modules". Which is the territory of OSGi.

Comment: That looks promising, i'll check it out. Thanks @Gimby

Comment: Warning: it is far from trivial to modularize an existing application. I'd stick with just rebuilding the application myself. Is there any particular problem you are trying to solve here? Say: guaranteeing uptime?

Comment: Ok thanks for the warning. No, it's just that the code in one class has to be changed from time to time (like every week or so) and the users don't have jdk so I need to repack the prog every time and resdistribute it. Was looking for a smooth and simple solution but if there is none I'll probably stick with the old procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use [java web start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html). If your user starts application via java web start it is automatically being updated if updates are available.

EDIT
It does not provide class-based granularity, but I believe this is not the real issue. It however provides the jar-based granularity, i.e. the newer version of jar is being downloaded only if it was changed.

Comment: The Java EE app servers that I use will only hot redeploy so many times before getting an out of memory error.  Better to repackage in my view.

Comment: @duffymo, I agree with you. I however do not think that OP *really* wants to be able to reload one particular class. IMHO it was just an example.

Comment: Actually in my case it is indeed about updating one particular class according to the case.

Comment: Java Web Start doesn't support class-based granularity, but it does support jardiffs.  I don't know how the jardiff format actually works, so I don't know what kind of jardiff would result from changing a single class.  (I'd like to think it's smarter than just a binary diff.)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not.

You should repackage OR design the one that should be adjusted to be configurable at runtime.  If you can modify it using a configuration database and factory that would be the only way to do it without repackaging.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could create another `jar` for the customized classes and put it into the classpath **before** the old jar, and the JVM will load the customized classes. But this is simply looking for trouble...

Better to build two jars, one with the non changing classes and another with the customized classes and rebuild the later when you need it.

Comment: The JVM isn't going to automagically reload the updated classes though. Once a class is loaded by a classloader, its there to stay until unloaded by some mechanism first. Putting a new copy of the same class in a different jar isn't going to help.